# .NET WebBrowser poor JavaScript performance

Tags: .net, performance, webbrowser-control

I am using the .NET WebBrowser Control (2.0) for viewing web sites on the Internet in my application – which works fine! Unfortunately we discovered a huge drawback on that: Speed. As far as I have found out, the control performs consistently **very** poorly with JavaScript (6000ms+ in sunspider vs. 150ms in IE10). This could also be verified by using the “Retro” mode of the Maxthon Browser, a minimum working example (i.e. a simple form containing only the browser and no other logic), and Visual Studio’s built-in browsers – they all perform equally bad.  All of them use the IE10 version of the control (turned on via registry), so in theory a similar performance can be expected, or so we thought. 
Looking with Spy++ at the differences between IE10 and programs using the hosted control, an additional wrapper for Shell DocObject View can be found: ShellEmbedding.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfu9n.jpg shows the wrapper in the lower part in DesktopGap's hosted WebBrowser control, while the IE's browser window can be seen without ShellEmbedding in the upper part.

This, I believe, is responsible for the poor performance – but neither do I know a way around this nor are there any good sources for this  - which leads me to my question:

Is there a way to speed up the WebBrowser Control’s performance?

So far our main idea was to somehow remove the ShellEmbedding and directly instantiate Shell DocObject View (if possible); GPU_RENDERING is enabled and IE10 mode active (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Additionally, it seems that CSS handling is also worse than in IE, so maybe there is a connection.

Cheers,

Claus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to reproduce the issue on other PCs, it seemed that my PC - or more specifically my user profile - was the issue. However we could not find out why exactly this was the case, so simply by resetting it, the WebBrowser's performance was within acceptable levels again.

Thanks for your efforts ;)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to check that you are using the correct doctype directive or the correct browser emulation mode.

I am also using the WebBrowser component and via registry, force it to use IE10 mode regardless of doctype directive (Setting "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\myexe.exe" to DWORD 10001 (decimal).

Tested this html page to see if there were a difference in js speed:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var tick, tock;
    function start() {
        tick = Date.now();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            testDiv.appendChild(span);
            testDiv.removeChild(span);
        }
        tock = Date.now();
        alert(tock - tick);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="start();">Click to start</button>
    <div id="testDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

On my computer, I got the following results:
IE10: ~430ms
WebBrowser app: ~470ms
Chrome: 48ms

As you can see, in my test, there seems to be very little difference between IE10 and the WebBrowser app. The difference could be that the app does other CPU handling in parallell that could take some milliseconds. However, the difference to chrome is a factor 10, which is quite amazing.

Regards,
David

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however we solved the problem already: Something was wrong with my user profile (or my registry, who knows?) and resetting it pushed IE performance :D